# Can I attach a hinge to click laminate flooring?

Tags: wood, mdf, hinges

This may seem like a strange question. Basically, I have some few click laminate floorings present with me and I would like to make a ping pong table from those leftovers.
I was following [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Upcycling-click-laminate-to-a-tabletennis-table-1/) tutorial. 
I would like to hinge the two halves of the ping pong table. So my question is, can the laminate hold the hinge and can it be folded into two ?

Cheers.

Comment: There's no reason this can't be done in theory at least. How well it will work in practice I think will depend on the specifics of the laminate which we don't know. I'd try an experiment with a spare piece of laminate, using the screws you plan to use and see if they hold strongly enough that you're confident the finished table will last.

Comment: I'd be concerned about how the laminate would hold together structurally while being folded; the linked article mentions some 2x4s in the parts list that I assume run between the pairs of legs (acting kind of like joists to the flooring). If you start to fold the table, then the laminate would have to hold up the 2x4s and the legs, which could pull it apart or strip the screws. I'd at least want to add extra blocking underneath to give the frame more rigidity.

Comment: @Robert Nubel Gotcha! much appreciated.